# SIFT method give me bad results, recognizing 4 shapes

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I'm trying to recognize playing cards with open cv, but I have some problems. Firstly I would like to recognize color (hearts, diamonds, spades or clubs). I was staring with red colors. So I detect color, and cut diamond or heart and try recognize with sift - i choose good matches and match color which will be have more (I'm sure its stupid, but I didnt have any idea how to do this). I get result like the one as follows:

[image: this]

This is code of my match function:

```
def match(img, models):
goods = []
for name, value in models:
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(name, None)
    kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    if des1 is None or des2 is None:
        continue
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
    matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
    good = []
    if matches is None:
        continue
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
            good.append([m])
    img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img, kp1, name, kp2, good, None, flags=2)
    plt.imshow(img3), plt.show()
    goods.append([len(good), value])
maxi = 0
ret = None
for l, v in goods:
    if l > maxi:
        maxi = l
        ret = v
if maxi < 3:
    return 0
return ret
```

If you have any tip, I will be grateful.

Comment: So the color detection and the crops is successful, you only have trouble on classify whether is diamond or heart right?

Comment: Yes, I only have problem with sift

Comment: SIFT doesn't emphsizes on classifying shapes, it's local invarient descriptor, primarily used to classify/match features of given image, for shape detection you need to get contours and then check for the sape or color related stuffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 4 model images, one for each shape.

First you should classify the color, so you only have to compare the image with 2 of the models (either heart/diamond or spade/club).

Now, as the color is not important anymore, you should binarize the image, a Gauss + Otsu should be enough, it can be done as follows:

```
# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
ret, th = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Finally I would do the feature matching of `th` with the 2 model images and the one that gets more feature mathings (`len(good)`) is the one you are looking for.

Note that the model images must be binarized and should be of the same size.

Hope this helped!